# webkit-slider-thumb disappearing when dragging

Tags: css, html, slider, range

When I go to drag the slider thumb of my html5 input type=range element the slider thumb itself disappears until you unclick onto one of the steps/values. Why does this happen, and is there some way I can make the thumb draggable and always be seen?

A solution that doesn't use jQuery would be ideal.

The jsfiddle of what I have so far: http://jsfiddle.net/0baryxfv/

Some of the code because I have to paste it here to use jsfiddle...:

```
    <div class="range-container">
    <input type="range" name="testerslider" min="0" max="4" step="1" list="testlist">
    <div class="label-container">
        <div class="label">test1sdfs ksjdfs kfhjs skjfhs skdjfshd ksjdhfsk fsdkjf hskfjh jsksjfhs kjshd jdhd.</div>
        <div class="label">test2sd sdf sdfs sdfsdf sfsdf sdfsdf sdfdfdff sdfff</div>
        <div class="label">test3 sfdsf sdfsd sdfsf sdfsdf</div>
        <div class="label">test4 sdfsf sfdsf sdfsdf sdfsdfs sfsfd sfdf</div>
        <div class="label">test5 sdfsf sfsfddf</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I just ran into something similar and it ended up being a CSS issue. A reset stylesheet was applying  `display: block` to every input, which `range` elements don't seem to like.

In the case of your JSFiddle, it seems that `webkit-flex-basis` is messing with the rendering. Try a `display` property change after the element has rendered, or explicitly setting `input[type=range]` to `display: inline-block` and see if that helps.